# Write logs from Google Compute Engine to Google Logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-logging

I have a Compute instance which does some work.
Each day the logs are written to a `<today>log` file i.e today will be `20200617.log`. The issue is, I need to SSH into the engine and open the logs, to see if everything is as it should.

Is there a way, to replicate that in the Google Cloud Platform i.e making the engine log to specific files each day, and then being able to view those logs in the Google Cloud Platform (maybe the logging module)?

I have thought about pushing the log-file to storage each, say, 5 minut - but that is not really optimal

Answer (score 1):

I guess installing Cloud Logging agent on your Compute instances will help your use case. It streams logs from common third-party applications and system software to Cloud Logging.

[About the Logging Agent](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/logging)

> Note: Same document followed by how to install the agent.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise that you install an [Ops agent](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent) provided by Google.

The Ops Agent serves as the main tool for gathering telemetry data from your Compute Engine instances. It consolidates the collection of logs, metrics, and traces into one streamlined process. Utilizing [Fluent Bit](https://fluentbit.io/) for logs, it enables high-throughput logging, while for metrics and traces, it leverages the [OpenTelemetry Collector](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/).

**Key features:**

- One-step download and installation/upgrade procedure.
- Streamlined YAML-based configuration for ease of use.
- Compatibility with common Linux and Windows distributions.
- Proxy support for enhanced connectivity.

**Logging features:**

Enhanced performance in contrast to the legacy Logging Agent, featuring:

- High throughput, leveraging multi-core architecture efficiently.
- Optimal resource management, including memory and CPU.

Diverse log sources are accommodated, including:

- Standard system logs such as /var/log/syslog and /var/log/messages for Linux, and Windows Event Log, seamlessly collected without configuration.
- File-based logs with customizable paths and refresh intervals.
- Journald daemon and systemd logs.
- Logs transmitted over TCP protocol.
- Logs forwarded via Forward protocol, utilized by Fluent Bit and Fluentd.

Adaptable processing capabilities include:

- Conversion of text logs into structured logs through JSON-based or regular-expression-based parsing.
- Log entry modification, enabling removal, renaming, or field setting.
- Log exclusion based on labels and regular expressions.
- Detection and consolidation of multiline language-exception logs from Java, Python, and Golang.

Support for third-party applications includes:

- Pre-configured integration for common application log file paths and formats.